# Why is a:hover showing two different colors?

Tags: css

When I hover my link normally it turns to green. However there is also red showing up around the link. I don't understand.

[image]

```
.myButtonRegister{
  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myButtonRegister a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the size of `<a>` link tag is size of the content it contains, so the background doesn't cover the entire parent element which it has a larger size.

You can force the link to have the same size as the container by adding:

```
.myButtonRegister a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

```css
.myButtonRegister {
  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 48px; /* added */
  /* padding-top: 10px; */
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myButtonRegister a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="myButtonRegister"><a href="#">Sample text</a></div>
```

I would suggest to get rid of the div container but only use the link tag.

```css
.myButtonRegister {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C22312;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.myButtonRegister:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="myButtonRegister" href="#">Sample text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

When hovering the `<a>` tag you are also triggering the hover on its parent element `.myButtonRegister`. Your html can be simplified from this:

```
<button class="myButtonRegister">
 <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
</button>
```

to this:

```
<a class="myButtonRegister">REGISTER</a>
```

Then trigger a hover animation on class `myButtonRegister`. Because both `button` tag and `a` tag can be used to render a button.